# Using s3, node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

i'm trying to make a http request using 'request' for nodeJS. But it doesn't work.

It keeps writing 'require is not defined'. I have uploaded my index.html file to my s3 bucket, as well as my node_modules folder and my package.json file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.20/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script data-main="js.config" src="js/r.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

const request = require('request');

</script>
```

This is how the index.html file looks like. It's not the whole file. But it's only the 'require' part is making trouble.. 
Let me know if you need any more info.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Um *require* is part of *serverside* js. Youre trying to call it on *userside*. May use something like *browserify* to resolve such userside dependencies.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417445/requiring-my-own-modules

Comment: You can't use `request` package on the client that way. Like @Jonasw pointed out, you need a bundler like webpack or Browserify to achieve that. However, you can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) from [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make such request without any node package.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the request package on a client side script in that way, pointed out by many of the comments posted. That being said, if you want to have an App with a Node JS Backend for the serverside, you probably shouldn't be using AWS S3 anyways. There are many options for you if you plan to make a Backend App with Node JS:

- AWS EC2 with Node JS
- AWS Lambda
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Some of these options, notably the EC2 and Lambda, have free tier options. Hopefully this helps you.